# PostgreSQL said: MultiXactId 1085002 has not been created yet -- apparent wraparound

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I got a weird error while I was writing to my Postgres database over Aurora PostgreSQL on AWS

PostgreSQL version 9.6.11

my tries to fix that issue on table admin_user

```
 Vacuum admin_user 
 Vacuum Freeze admin_user
```

I couldn't recreate the table as it's connected to all other tables and will cause a big mess

**Update question**

I cant access the table

[image]

Comment: Data corruption, perhaps caused by an old bug (you are 8 minor releases behind), perhaps due to hardware problems. If you can still read the table, do a `pg_dump` of the database and restore it to a new, pristine cluster (hopefully at the latest minor release). If you cannot read all rows from the table, you have to depend on whatever your hosting provider can do for you.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to show I can't access the table but I will try pg_dump

Comment: Meh. Then a `pg_dump` (which, after all, selects all data as well) will also fail. You are up to the mercy of your hosting provider. I'll try to write a helpful answer.

Answer (score 6):

For reasons that we probably cannot fathom here (could be a PostgreSQL software bug that might have been fixed by 9.6.19, could be a hardware problem), you have suffered data corruption.

Since you are using a hosted database and have no access to the database except through SQL, your options are limited.

The best is probably to use subtransactions to lift as many data as you can from the table (called `test` in this example):

```
/* will receive salvaged rows */
CREATE TABLE test_copy (LIKE test);
```

You can run something like this code:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   c CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM test;
   r test;
   cnt bigint := 0;
BEGIN
   OPEN c;

   LOOP
      cnt := cnt + 1;

      /* block to start a subtransaction for each row */
      BEGIN
         FETCH c INTO r;

         EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            /* there was data corruption fetching the row */
            RAISE WARNING 'skipped corrupt data at row number %', cnt;

            NOVE c;

            CONTINUE;
      END;

      /* row is good, salvage it */
      INSERT INTO test_copy VALUES (r.*);
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

Good luck.